# subprocess.py(476) hung

Tags: python, compression, subprocess, 7zip

I have some simple code using Pyunpack.

```
from pyunpack import Archive
import os.path
Archive(thing).extractall(os.path.dirname(thing))
```

Where `thing` is the path to a 7z file I'm trying to extract.

When I run the code, it gets stuck. Running `python -m trace --trace mycode.py` revealed that the code gets stuck on `subprocess.py(476): return func(*args)`

I have no idea why this would be or how to investigate. Any suggestions?

More below:

```
tempfile.py(233):     names = _get_candidate_names()
 --- modulename: tempfile, funcname: _get_candidate_names
tempfile.py(220):     if _name_sequence is None:
tempfile.py(221):         _once_lock.acquire()
tempfile.py(222):         try:
tempfile.py(223):             if _name_sequence is None:
tempfile.py(224):                 _name_sequence = _RandomNameSequence()
 --- modulename: tempfile, funcname: __init__
tempfile.py(121):         self.mutex = _allocate_lock()
tempfile.py(122):         self.normcase = _os.path.normcase
tempfile.py(226):             _once_lock.release()
tempfile.py(227):     return _name_sequence
tempfile.py(235):     for seq in xrange(TMP_MAX):
tempfile.py(236):         name = names.next()
 --- modulename: tempfile, funcname: next
tempfile.py(136):         m = self.mutex
tempfile.py(137):         c = self.characters
tempfile.py(138):         choose = self.rng.choice
 --- modulename: tempfile, funcname: rng
tempfile.py(126):         cur_pid = _os.getpid()
tempfile.py(127):         if cur_pid != getattr(self, '_rng_pid', None):
tempfile.py(128):             self._rng = _Random()
 --- modulename: random, funcname: __init__
random.py(97):         self.seed(x)
 --- modulename: random, funcname: seed
random.py(109):         if a is None:
random.py(110):             try:
random.py(111):                 a = long(_hexlify(_urandom(32)), 16)
random.py(116):         super(Random, self).seed(a)
random.py(117):         self.gauss_next = None
random.py(98):         self.gauss_next = None
tempfile.py(129):             self._rng_pid = cur_pid
tempfile.py(130):         return self._rng
tempfile.py(140):         m.acquire()
tempfile.py(141):         try:
tempfile.py(142):             letters = [choose(c) for dummy in "123456"]
 --- modulename: random, funcname: choice
random.py(273):         return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
tempfile.py(142):             letters = [choose(c) for dummy in "123456"]
 --- modulename: random, funcname: choice
random.py(273):         return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
tempfile.py(142):             letters = [choose(c) for dummy in "123456"]
 --- modulename: random, funcname: choice
random.py(273):         return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
tempfile.py(142):             letters = [choose(c) for dummy in "123456"]
 --- modulename: random, funcname: choice
random.py(273):         return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
tempfile.py(142):             letters = [choose(c) for dummy in "123456"]
 --- modulename: random, funcname: choice
random.py(273):         return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
tempfile.py(142):             letters = [choose(c) for dummy in "123456"]
 --- modulename: random, funcname: choice
random.py(273):         return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
tempfile.py(142):             letters = [choose(c) for dummy in "123456"]
tempfile.py(144):             m.release()
tempfile.py(146):         return self.normcase(''.join(letters))
 --- modulename: posixpath, funcname: normcase
posixpath.py(53):     return s
tempfile.py(237):         file = _os.path.join(dir, pre + name + suf)
 --- modulename: posixpath, funcname: join
posixpath.py(73):     path = a
posixpath.py(74):     for b in p:
posixpath.py(75):         if b.startswith('/'):
posixpath.py(77):         elif path == '' or path.endswith('/'):
posixpath.py(80):             path += '/' + b
posixpath.py(74):     for b in p:
posixpath.py(81):     return path
tempfile.py(238):         try:
tempfile.py(239):             fd = _os.open(file, flags, 0600)
tempfile.py(240):             _set_cloexec(fd)
 --- modulename: tempfile, funcname: _set_cloexec
tempfile.py(49):         try:
tempfile.py(50):             flags = _fcntl.fcntl(fd, _fcntl.F_GETFD, 0)
tempfile.py(55):             flags |= _fcntl.FD_CLOEXEC
tempfile.py(56):             _fcntl.fcntl(fd, _fcntl.F_SETFD, flags)
tempfile.py(241):             return (fd, _os.path.abspath(file))
 --- modulename: posixpath, funcname: abspath
posixpath.py(367):     if not isabs(path):
 --- modulename: posixpath, funcname: isabs
posixpath.py(61):     return s.startswith('/')
posixpath.py(373):     return normpath(path)
 --- modulename: posixpath, funcname: normpath
posixpath.py(339):     slash, dot = (u'/', u'.') if isinstance(path, _unicode) else ('/', '.')
posixpath.py(340):     if path == '':
posixpath.py(342):     initial_slashes = path.startswith('/')
posixpath.py(345):     if (initial_slashes and
posixpath.py(346):         path.startswith('//') and not path.startswith('///')):
posixpath.py(348):     comps = path.split('/')
posixpath.py(349):     new_comps = []
posixpath.py(350):     for comp in comps:
posixpath.py(351):         if comp in ('', '.'):
posixpath.py(352):             continue
posixpath.py(350):     for comp in comps:
posixpath.py(351):         if comp in ('', '.'):
posixpath.py(353):         if (comp != '..' or (not initial_slashes and not new_comps) or
posixpath.py(355):             new_comps.append(comp)
posixpath.py(350):     for comp in comps:
posixpath.py(351):         if comp in ('', '.'):
posixpath.py(353):         if (comp != '..' or (not initial_slashes and not new_comps) or
posixpath.py(355):             new_comps.append(comp)
posixpath.py(350):     for comp in comps:
posixpath.py(358):     comps = new_comps
posixpath.py(359):     path = slash.join(comps)
posixpath.py(360):     if initial_slashes:
posixpath.py(361):         path = slash*initial_slashes + path
posixpath.py(362):     return path or dot
tempfile.py(494):         try:
tempfile.py(495):             _os.unlink(name)
tempfile.py(496):             return _os.fdopen(fd, mode, bufsize)
__init__.py(210):             self._stderr_file = tempfile.TemporaryFile(prefix='stderr_')
 --- modulename: tempfile, funcname: TemporaryFile
tempfile.py(485):         if dir is None:
tempfile.py(486):             dir = gettempdir()
 --- modulename: tempfile, funcname: gettempdir
tempfile.py(265):     if tempdir is None:
tempfile.py(272):     return tempdir
tempfile.py(488):         if 'b' in mode:
tempfile.py(489):             flags = _bin_openflags
tempfile.py(493):         (fd, name) = _mkstemp_inner(dir, prefix, suffix, flags)
 --- modulename: tempfile, funcname: _mkstemp_inner
tempfile.py(233):     names = _get_candidate_names()
 --- modulename: tempfile, funcname: _get_candidate_names
tempfile.py(220):     if _name_sequence is None:
tempfile.py(227):     return _name_sequence
tempfile.py(235):     for seq in xrange(TMP_MAX):
tempfile.py(236):         name = names.next()
 --- modulename: tempfile, funcname: next
tempfile.py(136):         m = self.mutex
tempfile.py(137):         c = self.characters
tempfile.py(138):         choose = self.rng.choice
 --- modulename: tempfile, funcname: rng
tempfile.py(126):         cur_pid = _os.getpid()
tempfile.py(127):         if cur_pid != getattr(self, '_rng_pid', None):
tempfile.py(130):         return self._rng
tempfile.py(140):         m.acquire()
tempfile.py(141):         try:
tempfile.py(142):             letters = [choose(c) for dummy in "123456"]
 --- modulename: random, funcname: choice
random.py(273):         return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
tempfile.py(142):             letters = [choose(c) for dummy in "123456"]
 --- modulename: random, funcname: choice
random.py(273):         return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
tempfile.py(142):             letters = [choose(c) for dummy in "123456"]
 --- modulename: random, funcname: choice
random.py(273):         return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
tempfile.py(142):             letters = [choose(c) for dummy in "123456"]
 --- modulename: random, funcname: choice
random.py(273):         return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
tempfile.py(142):             letters = [choose(c) for dummy in "123456"]
 --- modulename: random, funcname: choice
random.py(273):         return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
tempfile.py(142):             letters = [choose(c) for dummy in "123456"]
 --- modulename: random, funcname: choice
random.py(273):         return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
tempfile.py(142):             letters = [choose(c) for dummy in "123456"]
tempfile.py(144):             m.release()
tempfile.py(146):         return self.normcase(''.join(letters))
 --- modulename: posixpath, funcname: normcase
posixpath.py(53):     return s
tempfile.py(237):         file = _os.path.join(dir, pre + name + suf)
 --- modulename: posixpath, funcname: join
posixpath.py(73):     path = a
posixpath.py(74):     for b in p:
posixpath.py(75):         if b.startswith('/'):
posixpath.py(77):         elif path == '' or path.endswith('/'):
posixpath.py(80):             path += '/' + b
posixpath.py(74):     for b in p:
posixpath.py(81):     return path
tempfile.py(238):         try:
tempfile.py(239):             fd = _os.open(file, flags, 0600)
tempfile.py(240):             _set_cloexec(fd)
 --- modulename: tempfile, funcname: _set_cloexec
tempfile.py(49):         try:
tempfile.py(50):             flags = _fcntl.fcntl(fd, _fcntl.F_GETFD, 0)
tempfile.py(55):             flags |= _fcntl.FD_CLOEXEC
tempfile.py(56):             _fcntl.fcntl(fd, _fcntl.F_SETFD, flags)
tempfile.py(241):             return (fd, _os.path.abspath(file))
 --- modulename: posixpath, funcname: abspath
posixpath.py(367):     if not isabs(path):
 --- modulename: posixpath, funcname: isabs
posixpath.py(61):     return s.startswith('/')
posixpath.py(373):     return normpath(path)
 --- modulename: posixpath, funcname: normpath
posixpath.py(339):     slash, dot = (u'/', u'.') if isinstance(path, _unicode) else ('/', '.')
posixpath.py(340):     if path == '':
posixpath.py(342):     initial_slashes = path.startswith('/')
posixpath.py(345):     if (initial_slashes and
posixpath.py(346):         path.startswith('//') and not path.startswith('///')):
posixpath.py(348):     comps = path.split('/')
posixpath.py(349):     new_comps = []
posixpath.py(350):     for comp in comps:
posixpath.py(351):         if comp in ('', '.'):
posixpath.py(352):             continue
posixpath.py(350):     for comp in comps:
posixpath.py(351):         if comp in ('', '.'):
posixpath.py(353):         if (comp != '..' or (not initial_slashes and not new_comps) or
posixpath.py(355):             new_comps.append(comp)
posixpath.py(350):     for comp in comps:
posixpath.py(351):         if comp in ('', '.'):
posixpath.py(353):         if (comp != '..' or (not initial_slashes and not new_comps) or
posixpath.py(355):             new_comps.append(comp)
posixpath.py(350):     for comp in comps:
posixpath.py(358):     comps = new_comps
posixpath.py(359):     path = slash.join(comps)
posixpath.py(360):     if initial_slashes:
posixpath.py(361):         path = slash*initial_slashes + path
posixpath.py(362):     return path or dot
tempfile.py(494):         try:
tempfile.py(495):             _os.unlink(name)
tempfile.py(496):             return _os.fdopen(fd, mode, bufsize)
__init__.py(211):             stdout = self._stdout_file
__init__.py(212):             stderr = self._stderr_file
__init__.py(218):         cmd = list(map(uniencode, self.cmd))
 --- modulename: unicodeutil, funcname: uniencode
unicodeutil.py(49):     if PY3:
unicodeutil.py(53):         if isinstance(s, unicode):
unicodeutil.py(55):     return s
 --- modulename: unicodeutil, funcname: uniencode
unicodeutil.py(49):     if PY3:
unicodeutil.py(53):         if isinstance(s, unicode):
unicodeutil.py(55):     return s
 --- modulename: unicodeutil, funcname: uniencode
unicodeutil.py(49):     if PY3:
unicodeutil.py(53):         if isinstance(s, unicode):
unicodeutil.py(55):     return s
 --- modulename: unicodeutil, funcname: uniencode
unicodeutil.py(49):     if PY3:
unicodeutil.py(53):         if isinstance(s, unicode):
unicodeutil.py(54):             s = s.encode('utf-8')
unicodeutil.py(55):     return s
 --- modulename: unicodeutil, funcname: uniencode
unicodeutil.py(49):     if PY3:
unicodeutil.py(53):         if isinstance(s, unicode):
unicodeutil.py(54):             s = s.encode('utf-8')
unicodeutil.py(55):     return s
__init__.py(220):         try:
__init__.py(221):             self.popen = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
__init__.py(222):                                           stdout=stdout,
__init__.py(223):                                           stderr=stderr,
__init__.py(224):                                           cwd=self.cwd,
__init__.py(225):                                           env=self.env,
 --- modulename: subprocess, funcname: __init__
subprocess.py(656):         _cleanup()
 --- modulename: subprocess, funcname: _cleanup
subprocess.py(459):     for inst in _active[:]:
subprocess.py(658):         if not isinstance(bufsize, (int, long)):
subprocess.py(661):         if mswindows:
subprocess.py(671):             if startupinfo is not None:
subprocess.py(674):             if creationflags != 0:
subprocess.py(678):         self.stdin = None
subprocess.py(679):         self.stdout = None
subprocess.py(680):         self.stderr = None
subprocess.py(681):         self.pid = None
subprocess.py(682):         self.returncode = None
subprocess.py(683):         self.universal_newlines = universal_newlines
subprocess.py(702):          errread, errwrite), to_close = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
 --- modulename: subprocess, funcname: _get_handles
subprocess.py(1103):             to_close = set()
subprocess.py(1104):             p2cread, p2cwrite = None, None
subprocess.py(1105):             c2pread, c2pwrite = None, None
subprocess.py(1106):             errread, errwrite = None, None
subprocess.py(1108):             if stdin is None:
subprocess.py(1109):                 pass
subprocess.py(1119):             if stdout is None:
subprocess.py(1121):             elif stdout == PIPE:
subprocess.py(1124):             elif isinstance(stdout, int):
subprocess.py(1128):                 c2pwrite = stdout.fileno()
subprocess.py(1130):             if stderr is None:
subprocess.py(1132):             elif stderr == PIPE:
subprocess.py(1135):             elif stderr == STDOUT:
subprocess.py(1137):             elif isinstance(stderr, int):
subprocess.py(1141):                 errwrite = stderr.fileno()
subprocess.py(1143):             return (p2cread, p2cwrite,
subprocess.py(1144):                     c2pread, c2pwrite,
subprocess.py(1145):                     errread, errwrite), to_close
subprocess.py(704):         try:
subprocess.py(705):             self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
subprocess.py(706):                                 cwd, env, universal_newlines,
subprocess.py(707):                                 startupinfo, creationflags, shell, to_close,
subprocess.py(708):                                 p2cread, p2cwrite,
subprocess.py(709):                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
subprocess.py(710):                                 errread, errwrite)
 --- modulename: subprocess, funcname: _execute_child
subprocess.py(1195):             if isinstance(args, types.StringTypes):
subprocess.py(1198):                 args = list(args)
subprocess.py(1200):             if shell:
subprocess.py(1205):             if executable is None:
subprocess.py(1206):                 executable = args[0]
subprocess.py(1208):             def _close_in_parent(fd):
subprocess.py(1215):             errpipe_read, errpipe_write = self.pipe_cloexec()
 --- modulename: subprocess, funcname: pipe_cloexec
subprocess.py(1167):             r, w = os.pipe()
subprocess.py(1168):             self._set_cloexec_flag(r)
 --- modulename: subprocess, funcname: _set_cloexec_flag
subprocess.py(1149):             try:
subprocess.py(1150):                 cloexec_flag = fcntl.FD_CLOEXEC
subprocess.py(1154):             old = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFD)
subprocess.py(1155):             if cloexec:
subprocess.py(1156):                 fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFD, old | cloexec_flag)
subprocess.py(1169):             self._set_cloexec_flag(w)
 --- modulename: subprocess, funcname: _set_cloexec_flag
subprocess.py(1149):             try:
subprocess.py(1150):                 cloexec_flag = fcntl.FD_CLOEXEC
subprocess.py(1154):             old = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFD)
subprocess.py(1155):             if cloexec:
subprocess.py(1156):                 fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFD, old | cloexec_flag)
subprocess.py(1170):             return r, w
subprocess.py(1216):             try:
subprocess.py(1217):                 try:
subprocess.py(1218):                     gc_was_enabled = gc.isenabled()
subprocess.py(1221):                     gc.disable()
subprocess.py(1222):                     try:
subprocess.py(1223):                         self.pid = os.fork()
subprocess.py(1228):                     self._child_created = True
subprocess.py(1229):                     if self.pid == 0:
subprocess.py(1300):                     if gc_was_enabled:
subprocess.py(1301):                         gc.enable()
subprocess.py(1304):                     os.close(errpipe_write)
subprocess.py(1308):                 data = _eintr_retry_call(os.read, errpipe_read, 1048576)
 --- modulename: threading, funcname: _after_fork
 --- modulename: subprocess, funcname: _eintr_retry_call
subprocess.py(474):     while True:
subprocess.py(475):         try:
subprocess.py(476):             return func(*args)
threading.py(1219):     _active_limbo_lock = _allocate_lock()
threading.py(1222):     new_active = {}
threading.py(1223):     current = current_thread()
 --- modulename: threading, funcname: currentThread
threading.py(1159):     try:
threading.py(1160):         return _active[_get_ident()]
threading.py(1224):     with _active_limbo_lock:
threading.py(1225):         for thread in _enumerate():
 --- modulename: threading, funcname: _enumerate
threading.py(1181):     return _active.values() + _limbo.values()
threading.py(1228):             if hasattr(thread, '_reset_internal_locks'):
threading.py(1229):                 thread._reset_internal_locks()
 --- modulename: threading, funcname: _reset_internal_locks
threading.py(700):         if hasattr(self, '_Thread__block'):  # DummyThread deletes self.__block
threading.py(701):             self.__block.__init__()
 --- modulename: threading, funcname: __init__
threading.py(260):         _Verbose.__init__(self, verbose)
 --- modulename: threading, funcname: __init__
threading.py(59):             if verbose is None:
threading.py(60):                 verbose = _VERBOSE
threading.py(61):             self.__verbose = verbose
threading.py(261):         if lock is None:
threading.py(262):             lock = RLock()
 --- modulename: threading, funcname: RLock
threading.py(122):     return _RLock(*args, **kwargs)
 --- modulename: threading, funcname: __init__
threading.py(132):         _Verbose.__init__(self, verbose)
 --- modulename: threading, funcname: __init__
threading.py(59):             if verbose is None:
threading.py(60):                 verbose = _VERBOSE
threading.py(61):             self.__verbose = verbose
threading.py(133):         self.__block = _allocate_lock()
threading.py(134):         self.__owner = None
threading.py(135):         self.__count = 0
threading.py(263):         self.__lock = lock
threading.py(265):         self.acquire = lock.acquire
threading.py(266):         self.release = lock.release
threading.py(270):         try:
threading.py(271):             self._release_save = lock._release_save
threading.py(274):         try:
threading.py(275):             self._acquire_restore = lock._acquire_restore
threading.py(278):         try:
threading.py(279):             self._is_owned = lock._is_owned
threading.py(282):         self.__waiters = []
threading.py(702):         self.__started._reset_internal_locks()
 --- modulename: threading, funcname: _reset_internal_locks
threading.py(567):         self.__cond.__init__()
 --- modulename: threading, funcname: __init__
threading.py(260):         _Verbose.__init__(self, verbose)
 --- modulename: threading, funcname: __init__
threading.py(59):             if verbose is None:
threading.py(60):                 verbose = _VERBOSE
threading.py(61):             self.__verbose = verbose
threading.py(261):         if lock is None:
threading.py(262):             lock = RLock()
 --- modulename: threading, funcname: RLock
threading.py(122):     return _RLock(*args, **kwargs)
 --- modulename: threading, funcname: __init__
threading.py(132):         _Verbose.__init__(self, verbose)
 --- modulename: threading, funcname: __init__
threading.py(59):             if verbose is None:
threading.py(60):                 verbose = _VERBOSE
threading.py(61):             self.__verbose = verbose
threading.py(133):         self.__block = _allocate_lock()
threading.py(134):         self.__owner = None
threading.py(135):         self.__count = 0
threading.py(263):         self.__lock = lock
threading.py(265):         self.acquire = lock.acquire
threading.py(266):         self.release = lock.release
threading.py(270):         try:
threading.py(271):             self._release_save = lock._release_save
threading.py(274):         try:
threading.py(275):             self._acquire_restore = lock._acquire_restore
threading.py(278):         try:
threading.py(279):             self._is_owned = lock._is_owned
threading.py(282):         self.__waiters = []
threading.py(1230):             if thread is current:
threading.py(1233):                 ident = _get_ident()
threading.py(1234):                 thread._Thread__ident = ident
threading.py(1235):                 new_active[ident] = thread
threading.py(1225):         for thread in _enumerate():
threading.py(1240):         _limbo.clear()
threading.py(1241):         _active.clear()
threading.py(1242):         _active.update(new_active)
threading.py(1243):         assert len(_active) == 1
subprocess.py(1228):                     self._child_created = True
subprocess.py(1229):                     if self.pid == 0:
subprocess.py(1231):                         try:
subprocess.py(1233):                             if p2cwrite is not None:
subprocess.py(1235):                             if c2pread is not None:
subprocess.py(1237):                             if errread is not None:
subprocess.py(1239):                             os.close(errpipe_read)
subprocess.py(1244):                             if c2pwrite == 0:
subprocess.py(1246):                             if errwrite == 0 or errwrite == 1:
subprocess.py(1250):                             def _dup2(a, b):
subprocess.py(1258):                             _dup2(p2cread, 0)
 --- modulename: subprocess, funcname: _dup2
subprocess.py(1254):                                 if a == b:
subprocess.py(1256):                                 elif a is not None:
subprocess.py(1259):                             _dup2(c2pwrite, 1)
 --- modulename: subprocess, funcname: _dup2
subprocess.py(1254):                                 if a == b:
subprocess.py(1256):                                 elif a is not None:
subprocess.py(1257):                                     os.dup2(a, b)
subprocess.py(1310):                 if p2cread is not None and p2cwrite is not None:
subprocess.py(1312):                 if c2pwrite is not None and c2pread is not None:
subprocess.py(1314):                 if errwrite is not None and errread is not None:
subprocess.py(1318):                 os.close(errpipe_read)
subprocess.py(1320):             if data != "":
subprocess.py(726):         if mswindows:
subprocess.py(734):         if p2cwrite is not None:
subprocess.py(736):         if c2pread is not None:
subprocess.py(741):         if errread is not None:
__init__.py(231):         self.is_started = True
__init__.py(232):         log.debug('process was started (pid=%s)', self.pid)
 --- modulename: __init__, funcname: pid
__init__.py(137):         if self.popen:
__init__.py(138):             return self.popen.pid
 --- modulename: __init__, funcname: debug
__init__.py(1139):         if self.isEnabledFor(DEBUG):
 --- modulename: __init__, funcname: isEnabledFor
__init__.py(1349):         if self.manager.disable >= level:
__init__.py(1351):         return level >= self.getEffectiveLevel()
 --- modulename: __init__, funcname: getEffectiveLevel
__init__.py(1338):         logger = self
__init__.py(1339):         while logger:
__init__.py(1340):             if logger.level:
__init__.py(1342):             logger = logger.parent
__init__.py(1339):         while logger:
__init__.py(1340):             if logger.level:
__init__.py(1341):                 return logger.level
__init__.py(233):         return self
 --- modulename: __init__, funcname: wait
__init__.py(257):         if timeout is not None:
__init__.py(263):         if self._thread:
__init__.py(268):             self._wait4process()
 --- modulename: __init__, funcname: _wait4process
__init__.py(273):         if self._outputs_processed:
__init__.py(276):         def remove_ending_lf(s):
__init__.py(282):         if self.popen:
__init__.py(283):             if self.use_temp_files:
__init__.py(284):                 if USE_POLL:
__init__.py(294):                     self.popen.wait()
 --- modulename: subprocess, funcname: wait
subprocess.py(1374):             while self.returncode is None:
subprocess.py(1375):                 try:
subprocess.py(1376):                     pid, sts = _eintr_retry_call(os.waitpid, self.pid, 0)
 --- modulename: subprocess, funcname: _eintr_retry_call
subprocess.py(474):     while True:
subprocess.py(475):         try:
subprocess.py(476):             return func(*args)
```

Comment: It means Python is waiting for an external command. Presumably the Pyarchive project uses a `7z` command line to do the work.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Is there a good way to see what it's waiting for?

Comment: No idea; the command line should show up in `ps faux`; search for your Python process, then look for child processes underneath to see what arguments are being passed to it.

Comment: That revealed it uses the CLI. Not sure what it's waiting for, or how to fix it, but at least I know why it's hung now. The arguments being passed do look a little strange.

`/usr/lib/p7zip/7z x -o/home/directory/im/extracting/to -- /home/path/to/my/zipped/file.7z`

Comment: And I found out what's wrong. The program had worked correctly the first time, successfully extracting the files. The CLI which normally just keeps going got stuck on the first file, waiting for a user to tell it whether to overwrite or rename the output.